# Create a method with a dictionary parameter where TKey and TValue types are indeterminate

Tags: c#, dictionary, types

Wondering whether it is possible to have a method with a dictionary parameter where TKey and TValue types are indeterminate.  For example, I may want to send a key of int and a value as a custom object, or a key of string and value of a different object.

Can this be done via generic objects, is the best practice with overloads, or is there another method I have not yet located?

```
public static SortedDictionary<??, ??> CreateSortedDictionary(Dictionary<??, ??> d)
{
    SortedDictionary<??, ??> rv = new SortedDictionary<??, ??>();

    enter code here...

    return rv;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just define the types on the method `CreateSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: It looks like you are defining SortedDictionary to have an int key and Entities.IdZone value. Was that a mistake?

Comment: Just edited that out.  Yes, I missed that when transposing the code.

Comment: Do you want to have different types of keys and values in one dictionary?

Comment: juharr-- So, how would the method be declared?

Comment: arekzyla--no, each time the method is called, the TKey will be one type, and the TValue will be one type.

Comment: What stops you from doing: SortedDictionary<T, V> CreateSortedDictionary<T, V>(Dictionary<T, V> d) ?

Comment: Like I had it, but the full signature would be `public static SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> CreateSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> d)`.  You will not have to specify the types when calling as they will be inferred from the dictionary you pass to it.

Comment: Okay--what stops me from doing what you suggested...I suppose nothing.  Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic types for the key and value, which can then be used for both the input and output dictionaries:

```
public static SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> CreateSortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> input)
{
    return new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the full method.  Extremely helpful.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped! Although, unless you're going to provide some extra functionality, it's a somewhat useless wrapper around the existing `SortedDictionary` constructor :)

Comment: The intent is to create a sorted dictionary, but modifying the keys to make sure there are no dups, as the original dictionary will easily have dups (by appending the key depending on the type, such as adding a decimal to a double).  Would it make sense to pose the final here?

Comment: Not sure I follow...dictionaries do not allow duplicate keys by definition, so it's impossible to have dupes to start with.

Comment: yes...a painful oversight on my part. I may need to send two lists.  I'm attempting to convert something from LISP, which it turns out can be much more complex to do in c#.

Comment: I think I will try:  public static SortedDictionary<double, TValue> CreateSortedDictionary<double, TValue>(List<KeyValuePair<double,TValue>> listKVP)

Comment: I see. Then you will just modify any duplicate keys?

Comment: yes, that's the plan.  my values are unique, just so happens I need to sort by the keys, which are likely not unique.

Comment: hmm. if your values are unique, why not use those for the keys?

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to sort by the keys...e.g. (1.0, "handle2") (1.0, "handle3") (2.0, "handle1") (2.5, "handle7") should be in that order.  Unless you know of a more clever way to do that.  Just finished I nice little method to convert the list of kvp to SortedDictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168869/discussion-between-rufus-l-and-edward-bagby).